# How to build a simple accordion layout with two columns next to each other in CSS?

Tags: jquery, css, html, accordion

Currently i'm building a simple accordion layout with 2 columns next to each other. The only problem i'm facing at the moment is the following:

When a user clicks on 1 of the accordions it will add a class 'is-open' to open the content below it. Sadly this will also give the same height to the column next to clicked accordion. I want every height to be 0 until it has the class 'is-open'.

The code I have for now can be found here:

```js
$('.message').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('is-open');
});
```

```css
.message {
  max-width: 49%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
  border-left: 1px solid blue;
  border-right: 1px solid blue;
}

.is-open .message--body {
  max-height: none;
}

.message--header {
  padding: 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

.message--header h4 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.message--body {
  padding: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.message--content {
  padding: 0 1em 1em 1em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <article class="message">
    <div class="message--header">
      <h4 class="is-size-6 has-text-purple has-text-weight-bold">Hosting van de website 1</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="message--body">
      <div class="message--content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus sed imperdiet felis. Pellentesque aliquet molestie tortor sit ut aliquet lacus facilisis amet volutpat.
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="message">
    <div class="message--header">
      <h4 class="is-size-6 has-text-purple has-text-weight-bold">Hosting van de website 2</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="message--body">
      <div class="message--content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus sed imperdiet felis. Pellentesque aliquet molestie tortor sit ut aliquet lacus facilisis amet volutpat.
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="message">
    <div class="message--header">
      <h4 class="is-size-6 has-text-purple has-text-weight-bold">Hosting van de website</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="message--body">
      <div class="message--content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus sed imperdiet felis. Pellentesque aliquet molestie tortor sit ut aliquet lacus facilisis amet volutpat.
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="message">
    <div class="message--header">
      <h4 class="is-size-6 has-text-purple has-text-weight-bold">Hosting van de website</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="message--body">
      <div class="message--content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus sed imperdiet felis. Pellentesque aliquet molestie tortor sit ut aliquet lacus facilisis amet volutpat.
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

When you click the top right column you will see the top left columns gets the height of the right top column. I'm trying to remove this but I can't find a good solution to this.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.message').click(function() {
 $(this).toggleClass('is-open');
});
```

```css
.message {
 width: 49%;
 float:left;
 margin:0;
 background-color:transparent;
 position:relative;
 border-bottom:1px solid blue;
 border-left:1px solid blue;
 border-right:1px solid blue;
}
.is-open .message--body {
    max-height: none;
      position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    background: #777;
    z-index: 9;
    min-width: 100%;
}
  
.message--header {
  padding:1em;
  cursor:pointer;
  position:relative;
}
.message--header h4 {
  display:inline-block;
}
.message--body {
  padding:0;
  max-height:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.message--content {
  padding: 0 1em 1em 1em;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
 <article class="message">
  <div class="message--header">
   <h4 class="is-size-6 has-text-purple has-text-weight-bold">Hosting van de website 1</h4>
  </div> 
  <div class="message--body">
   <div class="message--content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus sed imperdiet felis. Pellentesque aliquet molestie tortor sit ut aliquet lacus facilisis amet volutpat.
   </div>
  </div>
 </article>
 
 <article class="message">
  <div class="message--header">
   <h4 class="is-size-6 has-text-purple has-text-weight-bold">Hosting van de website 2</h4>
  </div> 
  <div class="message--body">
   <div class="message--content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus sed imperdiet felis. Pellentesque aliquet molestie tortor sit ut aliquet lacus facilisis amet volutpat.
   </div>
  </div>
 </article>
 
 <article class="message">
  <div class="message--header">
   <h4 class="is-size-6 has-text-purple has-text-weight-bold">Hosting van de website</h4>
  </div> 
  <div class="message--body">
   <div class="message--content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus sed imperdiet felis. Pellentesque aliquet molestie tortor sit ut aliquet lacus facilisis amet volutpat.
   </div>
  </div>
 </article>
 
 <article class="message">
  <div class="message--header">
   <h4 class="is-size-6 has-text-purple has-text-weight-bold">Hosting van de website</h4>
  </div> 
  <div class="message--body">
   <div class="message--content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus sed imperdiet felis. Pellentesque aliquet molestie tortor sit ut aliquet lacus facilisis amet volutpat.
   </div>
  </div>
 </article>

</div>
```

The desired result only can achieve by positions.Check this out

Comment: This is not ideal to be honest. How I see it the left side and the right side should be separate column rows so they will have there own height. Hope i'm clear enough

Comment: Yes you are my dear, but I have a point to make here.
1. This is collapse not accordion, accordion is something when only one item shows at once, if you click on any other then the opened one will close itself.
2. the thing you want to achieve is not possible by this way, in actual if you notice your DOM, then the height of left side message is not increasing, actually your right side message creating that height in DOM.

Answer (score -3):

I just fixed the problem by altering the style with vue. This is fixed!